# What does an element of a direct sum of free abelian groups look like?

Tags: notation, path-connected, free-abelian-group

If $H_n(X)$ is the homology group, and $\sum_{\lambda}H_n(X_{\lambda})$ is a direct sum such that $X$ is partitioned by path components with index $\lambda$, what does an element of $\sum_{\lambda}H_n(X_{\lambda})$ look like in terms of symbols?

I'm trying to show that, if $\gamma = \sum_{\lambda} \gamma$, $\theta_n:H_n(X) \rightarrow \sum_{\lambda}H_n(X_{\lambda})$ by cls $\gamma \mapsto$ cls $\gamma_{\lambda}$ is well defined but I'm not sure how I'd even define an element in $\sum_{\lambda}H_n(X_{\lambda})$.

$x \in \sum_{\lambda}H_n(X_{\lambda}) \Rightarrow x = ?$

Answer (score 1):

The direct sum, which I'll write as $\bigoplus_i A_i$, of Abelian groups
comprises **finite** formal sums of elements of the $A_i$. A typical
element is then $a_{i_1}+\cdots+a_{i_k}$ with $a_{i_j}\in A_{i_j}$.

In your application, you can define your map **provided** that
each of your $\text{cls}\,\gamma$ has the property that
$\text{cls}\,\gamma_\lambda$ is only nonzero for finitely many $\lambda$.
This may or may not be true...

Comment: So $x \in \sum_{\lambda}H_n(X_{\lambda}) \Rightarrow x = \sum_{\lambda}(x_{\lambda} \in H_n(X_{\lambda})) = \sum_{\lambda}(\text{cls }\gamma_{\lambda}) = \sum_{\lambda}(\gamma_{\lambda} + B_n(X_{\lambda}))$?

Comment: Added in that $\gamma = \sum_{\lambda} \gamma_{\lambda}$, where $\gamma_{\lambda}$ is the sum of terms in $\gamma$ that are in $X_{\lambda}$, for the notation that I'm using.